# Why does this synchronously-run async sleep hang?

Tags: .net, asynchronous, f#, sleep, synchronous

Consider this code:

```ml
open System
open System.Threading

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads (1, 1) |> ignore
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads (1, 1) |> ignore

let asyncOp i = async {
    printfn "started %i" i
    do! Async.Sleep 1000
    printfn "finished %i" i }

for i = 1 to 3 do Async.Start <| asyncOp i

printfn "read"
Console.ReadLine () |> ignore
```

I understand, to paraphrase the documentation for `SetMaxThreads`, that just one request to the thread pool can be active concurrently, and that other requests will remain queued until the thread becomes available. It prints

```
read
started 1
started 2
started 3
finished 3   // after a second
finished 2
finished 1
```

Incidentally, why do the "finished" lines print in reverse order?

Now change `do!` to `Async.RunSynchronously <|`. This time we get only

```
read
started 1
```

Why does it stop there? I would have expected the same as what you get when you replace the whole line with `Thread.Sleep 1000`:

```
read
started 1
finished 1   // after a second
started 2
finished 2   // after a second
started 3
finished 3   // after a second
```

Is it because `RunSynchronously` tries to create a new thread pool thread? (I'm not sure whether it does.)

Comment: No, because `sleep` is not blocking.

Comment: @Gus `Sleep` _is_ blocking.

Comment: The reversed order is not guaranteed. I ran it a few times, I got (3, 2, 1) most of the time but eventually got (1, 3, 2). They start so close together that the finish order is arbitrary.

Comment: Thanks for the observation, @TheQuickBrownFox. The reversed ordering was consistent over many runs for me, with 10 operations.

Comment: @CaringDev `Thread.Sleep` for sure, but `Async.Sleep` ? I don't think so.

Comment: @Gus my apologies, you’re absolutely right. Must have been doing too much C#… mixed up `Async.Sleep` with `Thread.Sleep` when it’s more like `Task.Delay`.

Comment: Anyways, that _is_ the reason for the deadlock. `Thread.Sleep` blocks the _current_ thread while (real) async with `RunSynchronously` needs the current + 1.

Comment: @CaringDev `SetMinThreads` and `SetMaxThreads` concern thread pool threads. Shouldn't there always be one thread pool thread available for running the `async` computations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the thread pool threads to 1 shows the difference between asynchronous operations using `do!` (and not blocking the current thread) and running synchronously (and thus blocking the current thread). The latter does not allow the async computation (here: sleep) to execute, as the thread that would be executing it is busy waiting for that computation to complete:

```
open System
open System.Threading

let onThread msg =
    let t = Thread.CurrentThread
    printfn "%s on thread %i (Pool: %b)" msg t.ManagedThreadId t.IsThreadPoolThread

ThreadPool.SetMinThreads (1, 1) |> ignore
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads (1, 1) |> ignore

let asyncOp i = async {
    printfn "started %i" i
    onThread "before sleep" // on thread pool already
    let s = Async.Sleep 1000
    onThread "going to wait"
    Async.RunSynchronously s // blocking THE thread pool thread
    onThread "after sleep"
    printfn "finished %i" i }

onThread "starting"
for i = 1 to 3 do Async.Start <| asyncOp i

printfn "read"
Console.ReadLine () |> ignore
```

Comment: Thanks -- although I do wonder why `RunSynchronously` can't just run the `Async` on the current thread (e.g. as a continuation) instead of running it on another thread. I suppose that's just the way it was written?

Comment: I think so, if you want to run it on the current thread you can use `Async.StartImmediate` or `Async.StartImmediateAsTask`. BTW: your question highlights very well why `Async.RunSynchronously` inside and async is not a good idea.

Comment: The thing is that it could already be running, so we have to wait for it to complete.
I guess there _could_ be an implementation that would run it kind of as a continuation but that would require locking and... just not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Note that after switching to `Async.RunSynchronously`, the code hangs even when running just one operation.

The [`ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads?view=net-6.0) docs state:

> You cannot set the maximum number of worker threads or I/O completion threads to a number smaller than the number of processors on the computer.

Apparently that's not quite true. You can set the value lower (no exception is thrown) but perhaps it means to suggest that this a very bad idea. However, I have noticed that even after upping the thread counts to 12 or 13 the code still hangs when running 100 async operations. Going up to 24 threads allows it to complete.

For me, `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads()` returns `(32767, 1000)` by default. This suggests to me that the .NET threading system really isn't designed to work with such low numbers of threads and that you shouldn't be reducing them to anywhere near 1.

The `SetMaxThreads` docs also say:

> Use caution when changing the maximum number of threads in the thread pool. While your code might benefit, the changes might have an adverse effect on code libraries you use.

If you're trying to achieve a particular behaviour by changing the ThreadPool max threads then I would suggest exploring a different approach.

Comment: Thank you @TheQuickBrownFox, worthwhile speculations. For the record, I'm setting the number of threads to 1 purely for experimentation and understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/tutorials/async) says about Async.RunSynchronously:

> When to use it:
>
> If you need it, use it only once in an application - at the entry point for an executable.
> When you don't care about performance and want to execute a set of other asynchronous operations at once.
>
> What to watch out for:
>
> Calling Async.RunSynchronously blocks the calling thread until the execution completes.